# Make base URL accessible throughout React app (and different for dev and prod)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have been developing a React and Node/Express app on my laptop, and now want to get it uploaded. One inconvenience I'm having is in the React app I define the same base URL (address of the Node server) in multiple modules.

```
const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/';
```

I will now have to go through and change each of these to a new cloud address. So I'm looking for two solutions:

1. How can I define my base URL (address of Node server) once across to whole React app and use it in each module?
2. How can I have it so it automatically changes depending on whether I'm running dev version on my laptop or prod version in the cloud?

Comment: `import { baseUrl } from 'path/to/config'`?

Comment: Ah, so much more simple than what I was thinking. Thanks. Do you have a solution for 2?

Comment: The simplest way to solve that is to have the Express app serve the React app in production and use a proxy in development, then you can make all of your requests *relative* (e.g. `'/api/endpoint'` instead of `'protocol://wheres.my.server/api/endpoint'`) - [here's](https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit) a project I set up to do that, for example.